# Code to get access token for pinterest

Tags: javascript, java, access-token, pinterest

I am trying to fetch data from pinterest for which I need access token.
Can you please help me with the **code** to get access token for Pinterest.

Comment: You ask about Java or Javascript?

Comment: You either have to use the generator linked below, or you can use the SDK to login -- PDK.login({scope}, callback) -- and then the token is available under -- PDK.getSession() --

Comment: @ZackArgyle, Could you provide an example of the login call and accessing the token? The Pinterest API doesn't have a complete example of this (that I have been able to find).

Comment: Just came across your github: https://github.com/pinterest/pinterest-api-demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Access Token Generator](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/) for testing

Comment: This is not working anymore. I am also looking for help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150697/generate-pinterest-access-token-dynamically-with-php-api