# Generate Pinterest access token dynamically with PHP API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, pinterest

I developed a Pinterest plugin for WordPress users. Now, I am facing token generation problem with Pinterest API. I have set and configure accordingly to [API docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/). In **Step 1** you get an access code and in **Step 2**, you need to request for access token with the help of access code. Step 1 going to succeed but in Step 2 throwing error response.

I already asked to Pinterest Support through email but they are saying:

> We're a small team right now and we can't offer development support or
> consult for the API just yet. For more support around using our API,
> we encourage you to use developer resources like **Stack Overflow**.

**The code I did:**
I already made an [APP](https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/) and used the give App ID and Secret, and redirect URL also set in APP same below:

```
$client_id = "&client_id=496200555XXXXXXXX1778834";
$client_secret = "&client_secret=48d62d7c21aa432bb5320c0aeXXXXXXXXXXX75933f6295db1bae61ffa66ca31";
$authorization_url = "https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?";
$response_type = "response_type=code";
$state = "&state=weblizar_app";
$scope = "&scope=read_public,read_relationships";
$redirect_uri = "&redirect_uri=https://weblizar.com/pinterest-access-token.php";
$access_token_url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?";
$grant_type = "grant_type=authorization_code";

// Step 1: get authorization code
$access_code_url = $authorization_url . $response_type . $redirect_uri . $client_id . $scope . $state;
echo "<a href=$access_code_url>Get Authorization Code</a>";

// Step 2: exchange the access token
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $authorization_code = $_GET['code'];
    $access_code_url = $access_token_url . $grant_type . $client_id . $client_secret ."&code=" .$authorization_code; echo "<br>";
    
    echo "Curl post URL - "; echo "<br>";
    $ch = curl_init();
    echo $url = $access_code_url;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $result = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    
    echo "Curl Post Response"; echo "<br>";
    echo "<pre>";   
    print_r($result);  
    echo "<pre>";
}
```

**Response Returned After Step 2**

```
{
  "message": "405: Method Not Allowed",
  "type": "http"
}
```

As everyone knows [Pinterest token generation URL](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/) no more available for users or closed down.

You can test, the code is live on site: https://weblizar.com/pinterest-access-token.php

Any kind of help really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The step of exchanging the code for a token has to be performed server-side, not by just having the user click on a link. (It contains your client secret for crying out loud, so that this doesn’t belong on the client side should be obvious!) And it needs to be a POST request - you are getting this error, because the browser issues a _GET_ request when following that link.

Comment: Should I use the curl for the second step? please guide me.

Comment: Use whatever you want, as long as it is capable of making a POST request ...

Comment: You are not sending it as a POST with curl.

Comment: @Frank now since you have the answer, update the answer here so that others can benefit.

Comment: Sorry! but I didn't get any correct answer yet. The code I applied from a blog,